# pictures in a table like a traffic light

Tags: html, button

I have three pictures a picture of a dog, a bear and a cat. My goal is to turn them into a traffic light sequence going from bear, to cat, to dog.using a button and an array, The button is the part I'm confused by as I want all the pictures to be in a vertical line with a "change animal" button at the top. I'm quite new to Html  so I'm not great at it.

```
<table border="0" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://i0.wp.com/cdn.bgr.com/2015/10/bear.jpg?w=625">
    </td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg">
    </td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_830/s_f/o_1/cx_0/cy_220/cw_1255/ch_1255/APL/uploads/2014/11/dog-breed-selector-australian-shepherd.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code you already have?

Comment: Google for JavaScript simple gallery implementations.  Your code will be rather close.

Comment: i realised im trying to do html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a traffic light with animals.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var td = document.querySelectorAll("td");
var arr = ['#F00','#FF0','#0F0'];
var item = 0;

td[item + 1].style.backgroundColor = arr[item];

btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  
  td[item + 1].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';  
  item = (item > 1) ? 0 : item + 1 ;  
  td[item + 1].style.backgroundColor = arr[item];
  
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 150px;
}
table img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; 
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button>CHANGE ANIMAL</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://i0.wp.com/cdn.bgr.com/2015/10/bear.jpg?w=625">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_830/s_f/o_1/cx_0/cy_220/cw_1255/ch_1255/APL/uploads/2014/11/dog-breed-selector-australian-shepherd.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For some reason the top section of the code isn't working for me when  i run it elsewhere, do you know why this might be

Comment: @Isabellaj Here is a fiddle link, try that code and see if it works: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/4k0h4pwj/1/